# jQuery: how to express the width of a div + a few more pixels?

Tags: jquery, width, jquery-animate

I want to animate a div to the left, to the width of the div + 100px.

I have this code:

```
$('#mydiv').animate({left:-$('#mydiv').outerWidth()},1000);
```

This animates it in 1000 milliseconds to the left, to the distance of the width of #mydiv.

How can I add 100 more pixels to that?

Would be grateful for your expertly advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try this instead:

```
$('#mydiv').animate({left:-($('#mydiv').width() + 100)},1000);
```

Comment: Beautiful, than you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`$('#mydiv').animate({left:-($('#mydiv').outerWidth() + 100)},1000);`

Comment: Thank you! This is simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var width = $('#mydiv').outerWidth();
$('#mydiv').animate({
    left: (width + 100)
},1000);
```

Not sure why you need the subtraction operator before the left value?